# Changing the height of an existing, visible TextView

Tags: android

Hi I'd like to programatically increase the height allocated to a TextView, and have the activity layout redrawn accordingly (the text view has a maximum height until the user clicks it, then it takes up all height required, wrap_content).

setHeight() isn't working, even coupled with invalidate() or postInvalidate(). I am able to change the contents of the TextBox with setText() but it isn't altering the existing specified height.

Android 1.5 under the 1.6 SDK.

Comment: As a follow up I have discovered I can set the height to arbitrary values, but currently can't work out how to set the height to wrap_content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't test that , but try to create new Layout params and assign it to a view
This is for a button, but idea is same.

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 0;
            shareBtn.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);
            shareBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Many thanks Alex. It works. I did try something similar but was getting exceptions inside Android layout stuff ... looking at what I wrote, the problem was I was using the wrong LayoutParams class. There is more than one.